# Why do the Beta Testers all have the lowest scores?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

On Stackoverflow, I am wondering why all the members with the "Beta Tester" badge seem to have low karma scores compared to most of the others?  It looks like an average of about 200 for them. Does that mean they participated in the Beta and then never came back?  If so, why would they come in the first place and why didn't they stick with it?  Was an initial temporary incentive to participate involved perhaps?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're just looking at the ones that were recently awarded. The conditions for having the Beta badge [are as follows](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/#comment-14705):

> You get the beta badge by having at least three bronze badges and an account start date prior to 9/16/08.

Most of the Beta badges were awarded on or around 9/16 of last year. The rest have been trickling in as people have been earning those three bronze badges (which is a very low bar). Seeing as they're getting to them now, it's not surprising that they aren't very active.

Here are some active users with the Beta badge:

- [Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill) 48,145
- [Joel Coehoorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3043/joel-coehoorn) 46,281
- [Bill the Lizard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard) 40,409
- [Konrad Rudolph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968/konrad-rudolph) 39,686
- [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) 37,087
- [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1) 14,491

Comment: I was wondering why people were still getting Beta badges.

Comment: @ Rob: as kyle said, you don't get it until you finally recieve the third bronze badge. I was wondering the same thing Rob. Perhaps they should show the members with the really high scores as well.

Comment: What are the conditions for the other SO family sites?

Comment: @bdonlan Exactly the same.

Comment: But with a different date I suppose.

Comment: Right, but what dates? :)

Comment: I assume that the conditions are the same, with the required date being the date that that site publicly launched. It's too late to get one on SF, and there won't be one here on Meta (since we were never in beta) but if you don't already I suggest getting an account on SU before it launches so you can get the badge.

Comment: @bdonlan: I suspect that the date for SF is 5/26, as that's the day that SF went into "public beta" (which I suppose it's still in, as there are no "out of beta" announcements on the blog: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/server-fault-public-beta-launches/

Comment: You can have my beta badge when you pry it from my cold dead account

Comment: <sniff> I want a beta badge.

Comment: Maybe you could get them to merge your account into an early one that has been abandoned.

Comment: @bdonlan, meta does not have the beta badge